# How to Get a List of All Post Types Which Have Published Posts / Exclude Some Post Types in WordPress using get_post_types() function?

Tags: php, wordpress

### Use of get_post_types() Function

---

I want to list all the post types on my website [tutsinsider](https://www.tutsinsider.com) on the search page, if the search query has no posts to show, display the list of post types that have published posts. Or even if I want to exclude some of the post types according to need. I want to use the get_post_types() function. Below is my code and an example

#### Post Types

| Post Types | No of Published Posts |
| --- | --- |
| one | 10 |
| two | 12 |
| three | 0 |
| four | 2 |
| five | 15 |

The post type **three** has no **published** posts, and post type **four** has 2 published posts. I want to exclude these from the list.
But, when I try to list using get_post_types, it lists all the posts.
I am using the below code.

```
<?php

$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false,
);

$output = 'names'; // 'names' or 'objects' (default: 'names')
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or' (default: 'and')

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );

if ( ! empty ( $post_types ) ) { // If there are any custom public post types.

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
        echo '<li>' . $post_type . '</li>';
    }

    echo '<ul>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

Hi,
After searching a lot and applying different techniques, I came up with this solution. I used the below code and got all the categories that have **post status = published**.
Since I have similar names of **custom post types** and **categories**, therefore, the below function came in handy for me.

### Function : get_categories($args)

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent'  => 0
    ) );

    $category_list = array();
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $category_list[] = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a> ';
    }

    echo implode( ', ', $category_list );
?>
```

Further, when I acquired the list of all the categories, I excluded the ones which have less number of posts or which I wanted not to list.
I used the **if() statement** within **foreach-loop** and truncated those unwanted categories from the list.

#### Complete Code

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
  'orderby' => 'name'   
  'parent'  => 0
) );

$category_list = array();
foreach($categories as $category){
  if($category->name != 'unwanted-1' && $category->name != 'unwanted-2) :
    $category_list[] = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a> ';
  }  
    echo implode( ', ', $category_list );
  endif;
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/coffeepostal/b713fc6dfbad450f81c6d2ba7520f085)